# CRM 2013 - Inconsistent javascript issue crash the web client and user needs to reopen

Tags: crm

We are using CRM 2013 on premise version and almost 600 users are using it. We have some inconsistent JavaScript issue (following is the log for same) which happens to users in a day or two. When this issue occurs user can not work in system and they have to open new instance of CRM.

Does anybody knows about this error?

```
<CrmScriptErrorReport>

  <ReportVersion>1.0</ReportVersion>

  <ScriptErrorDetails>

   <Message>Unable to get property 'location' of undefined or null reference</Message>

   <Line>1</Line>

   <URL>/_static/_common/scripts/main.js?ver=1676323357</URL>

   <PageURL>/main.aspx#313155368</PageURL>

   <Function>anonymous($p0,$p1,$p2){this.$3_3.get_currentIFrame()&&Mscrm.PerformanceTracing.write("Unload",this.$3_3.get_currentIFrame().src);this.$H_3=$p0.toString();this.$26_3();this.$1A_3();this.$1J_3();if($p0.get_isLocalServer())$p0.get_query()["pagemode"]="iframe</Function>

   <CallStack>

    <Function>anonymous($p0,$p1,$p2){this.$3_3.get_currentIFrame()&&Mscrm.PerformanceTracing.write("Unload",this.$3_3.get_currentIFrame().src);this.$H_3=$p0.toString();this.$26_3();this.$1A_3();this.$1J_3();if($p0.get_isLocalServer())$p0.get_query()["pagemode"]="iframe";addPassiveAuthParameters($p0);var$v_0=$p0.toString();if(IsNull($p2))$p2=false;var$v_1=this.$18_3($p0,$p2);if($v_1){if(this.$2z_3()){window.location.reload();return}this.$2d_3();this.$1s_3();Mscrm.PerformanceTracing.write("Navigate",$v_0);!Mscrm.Utilities.isIE()&&this.raiseEvent(Mscrm.ScriptEvents.UpdateTopLocation,null);this.$3_3.get_currentIFrame().contentWindow.location.replace($v_0)}else{this.$10_3();var$v_2=this.get_contentWindow().Sys.Application.findComponent("crmPageManager");if($v_2){!Mscrm.Utilities.isIE()&&$v_2.raiseEvent(Mscrm.ScriptEvents.UpdateTopLocation,null);var$v_3={};$v_3["sourceUri"]=Mscrm.Utilities.getContentUrl(null);$v_2.raiseEvent(Mscrm.ScriptEvents.IFrameReactivated,$v_3)}}window.self.InnerIFrameSrcChangeTimestamp=(newDate).getTime();this.title=$p1;if(window.LOCID_UI_DIR==="RTL"&&$p0.toString().indexOf("PersonalWall")>=0&&window.UseTabletExperience)this.$3_3.get_currentIFrame().style.position="RELATIVE"}</Function>

   </CallStack>

  </ScriptErrorDetails>

  <ClientInformation>

   <BrowserUserAgent>Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3)</BrowserUserAgent>

   <BrowserLanguage>en-US</BrowserLanguage>

   <SystemLanguage>en-US</SystemLanguage>

   <UserLanguage>en-US</UserLanguage>

   <ScreenResolution>1366x768</ScreenResolution>

   <ClientName>Web</ClientName>

   <ClientTime>2015-04-20T15:41:12</ClientTime>

  </ClientInformation>

  <ServerInformation>

    <OrgLanguage>1033</OrgLanguage>

    <OrgCulture>1033</OrgCulture>

    <UserLanguage>1033</UserLanguage>

    <UserCulture>1033</UserCulture>

    <OrgID>{E8BBA7AE-A552-DE11-B475-001E0B4882E2}</OrgID>

    <UserID>{614837CD-448B-DE11-A5E1-005056970D6C}</UserID>

    <CRMVersion>6.1.2.112</CRMVersion>

  </ServerInformation>

</CrmScriptErrorReport>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would ensure you are on at least Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 SP1 as that takes care of many of the JavaScript issues like the ones you are seeing above.  You can download that from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43109.  In addition to that there is an Update Rollup 1 for Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 Service Pack 1 that is available as well at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2953252 .

In addition to that, you can typically ignore/hide these script errors by changing a system setting as described here to either send these error reports to Microsoft always or to never send them to Microsoft.  This has worked for me in environments where I was receiving similar JavaScript errors that were internal to the CRM platform code vs. custom JavaScript code errors.

"1.Navigate to Settings >> Administration >> Privacy Preferences

2.Click on Error Reporting and check the box for “Specify the Web application error notification preferences on behalf of users“ and  choose either of below options:

Automatically send an error report to Microsoft without asking the user for permission

Never Send an error report to Microsoft

Above steps will be applied Organization wide.
"

If these steps do not work, then it would probably be a good scenario to log a support case with the Microsoft Dynamics CRM Support team given the impact to your organization to have them dig in and as needed to work with the product team to figure out the root cause of this problem.